# How do I stop Pinguy Builder 4.X from installing gnome and gdm?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

After building a JWM and Ubuntu based OS I encountered the problem that PinguyBuilder installs Gnome when running the dist option. I do not want this.
Thanks in advance,
James

P.S. This may not be possible as Pinguy OS uses gnome as a base; however, if there is some editable code I would happily use it.
Should I use backup instead

Comment: ? I was using Pinguy Builder?

Comment: To make an installer

Comment: Have made edit!